# insert missing row based on repeating series for hourly sequence between 0 and 23

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to replace missing value of hour data based on a csv file. I used the following code although it does not capture all hour value in the sequence between 0-23. for example where the next last number in the list is 22 it does not add a new row for 23.

link to hour data: http://pastebin.com/MUgCgzhL
Link to output : http://pastebin.com/PzzPK9ZT

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_csv('path to csv')
data2 = data.copy()
data2_index = 0

for index , row in data.iterrows():
    #Set the current value of the number and the next value in the list    
    current_value = data['hour'][index]
    next_value = data['hour'][min(max(-1,index + 1),data['hour'].size-1)]

    if current_value + 1 == next_value or current_value == next_value + 3 or index == 0:
        #Write in the value as per normal if the following value is the same
        data2.loc[data2_index] = data.loc[index]
        data2_index = data2_index + 1
    else:
        #Otherwise, add in new rows till we get to the value in the next row in the original df
        if next_value < current_value :
            current_value = 0
            target_value = next_value - 1 
            data2.loc[data2_index] = data.loc[index]
            data2_index = data2_index + 1
            for x in range(current_value+1,target_value+1):
                data2.loc[data2_index] = ['0','0','0','0','0',x,'0','0']
                data2_index = data2_index + 1        
                print (data2)
                data2.to_csv('outputpacth')
```

Comment: What's the question here?

Comment: I need to create new rows where there is missing  data on hour

Comment: Can you please add sample output. It will be really helpful

Comment: @SayaliSonawane here is the link for the output: http://pastebin.com/PzzPK9ZT

Comment: if you have access to output file then why don't you read that csv file in python?